# Quicktags external functions file

Tags: functions, tinymce

I have added shortcode buttons to the WordPress tinyMCE text editor using the WordPress quicktags function.

This works fine when in functions.php, however I need it to be in an external functions file which I am including in functions.php. For some reason it does not work in my external functions file.

The external function file definitely works, sinceother functions work fine within it.

I have also removed all code from the external file except the quicktags function to see if there is a conflict but it still does not work.

Any ideas on how i can get this to work?

```
function appthemes_add_quicktags() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        QTags.addButton( 'eg_builderEmail', 'Email Link', '[getBuilderData name="domainPleskEmail"]@[getBuilderData name="domainName"]', '', 'builderEmail', 'builderEmail', 1 );
        QTags.addButton( 'eg_builderCompanyName', 'Company Name', '[getBuilderData name="domainTradingName"]', '', 'builderCompanyName', 'builderCompanyName', 1 );
        QTags.addButton( 'eg_builderMainNumber', 'Main Number', '[getBuilderData name="domainMainPhoneNumber"]', '', 'MainNumber', 'MainNumber', 1 );
        QTags.addButton( 'eg_builderMobileNumber', 'Mobile Number', '[getBuilderData name="domainBusinessMobile"]', '', 'MobileNumber', 'MobileNumber', 1 );
        QTags.addButton( 'eg_builderDomainName', 'Domain Name', '[getBuilderData name="domainName"]', '', 'DomainName', 'DomainName', 1 );
        QTags.addButton( 'eg_builderTown', 'Town', '[getBuilderData name="domainWebTown"]', '', 'builderTown', 'builderTown', 1 );
        QTags.addButton( 'eg_builderCounty', 'County', '[getBuilderData name="domainWebCounty"]', '', 'builderCounty', 'builderCounty', 1 );
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'appthemes_add_quicktags' );
```

Comment: Please post that external quicktag adding function so we can see if everything's alright with it.

Comment: @jimihenrik i have edited my question with the function

Comment: Worth noting it works fine when in functions.php

Comment: Well that's strange. I copy-pasted your code to my external writer_editor_cleanup.php and it works fine. And for me it's even more than one external file away, I have `require_once( 'library/admin.php' );` in functions.php, and in my admin.php I have `require_once( 'includes/SU_Writer_Editor_Cleanup.php' );` so doesn't seem like the file being external is the problem. You do have `<?php` in the front of the file and `?>` at the end right?

Comment: And by the way, you probably noticed, but I'll say anyway; that this adds the quicktag buttons only to the text-editor, not to the visual editor.

Comment: @jimihenrik Hmmm that is strange! yeah i have the <?php ?>

Comment: @jimihenrik have you placed your require_once at the top of your functions.php?

Comment: It's up there, not quite the first one though. But I'm using [Bones](http://themble.com/bones/) so that affects where everything's loaded for me. edit: I don't think that should matter though, I mean if you include the file at the same place where you had the code working in the file that is.

Comment: @jimihenrik I've got it to work! I had to create a second functions file and call it in like this:
include_once('../buildertags.php');
for some reason my other function file works fine like this:
include_once('stFunctions.php');}

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Lol well I don't know if I was really of help, but glad you got it sorted out :)